# Making an efficient and healthy db call for a real-time browser game

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

I'm doing a calculation for a real-time browser game, where users can invest some of their balances to the site. I need to update their invest's based on `AN_AMOUNT_FROM_SITE` and their percentage of shares (see `PROFIT` line). This function needs to run every 20-100 ms because `AN_AMOUNT_FROM_SITE` is coming consistently.

When this process finish, I'm saving a few unimportant data in `callback()`.

When `FUNDS` collection has a few hundred document, this process will be very slow. Are there any ways I can reduce this process with Mongo to make it more efficient?

```
FUNDS.aggregate().group({ //get sum of invested amounts
        _id: '$id1',
        invest_total: { $sum: '$invest_amount'}}).exec(function ( e1, d ) {
             if( !e1 && d ){
                FUNDS.find().exec(function( e2, invests ){ //find all invests
                    if ( !e2 && invests ){ 
                      //calculate PROFIT value to each invest according to their rates (it can be +/-)
                        for (var i = 0; i < invests.length; i++) { 

                        var invest_amount = invests[i].invest_amount,
                            invest_id     = invests[i].invest_id,
                            PROFIT        = AN_AMOUNT_FROM_SITE * invest_amount / d[0].invest_total; // 
                            //update each invest 
                            FUNDS.findOneAndUpdate({ 'invest_id': invest_id }, { $inc: { 'invest_profit': profit } }, function(e3) {
                                callback()
                            });
                    };
                }

                })
             }
})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The power of the aggregation framework is it's ability to iterate over the dataset in various useful ways *without* incurring extra round trips between the database and the app.

Your code uses one stage for aggregation (grouping by `id1`), and then jumps out of aggregation to iterate over the entire `FUNDS` collection for every user. That is very expensive, giving you [exponential time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Exponential_time) or worse.

The code below makes the database do all the heavy lifting in [3 aggregation framework stages](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/), and returns an array with all the necessary data.

1. pivot over the user_id, calculating `invest_amount`, saving unique records in an array called `records`
2. unwind `records`. Now you have your original documents, but with a useful extra field.
3. calculate profit

Then we end up with an array of objects which can be iterated over, applying the the `$inc` update.

```
FUNDS.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": '$id1',
            "invest_total": {"$sum": "$invest_amount"},
            "records": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$records"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "invest_id": "$records.invest_id",
            "user_id": "$records.id1",
            "invest_total": "$invest_total",
            "invest_amount": "$records.invest_amount",
            "profit": {
                "$divide": [
                    { "$multiply": ["$records.invest_amount", AN_AMOUNT_FROM_SITE ] },
                    "$invest_total"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function(err,docs){
    docs.forEach(function(d){
        FUNDS.findOneAndUpdate(
            { "invest_id": d.invest_id},
            { "$inc": { 'invest_profit': d.profit } },
            function(e3){
                callback();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your awesome explanation and help, this was what I want.. But Mongodb doesnt let me use `$$ROOT` when pushing documents to records:  `FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.`

Comment: I noticed I was using old version of mongodb.